# What does Sequence[2,4]^2 mean?

Tags: pattern-matching, sequence

I am learning pattern matching. An example that confuse me is as follows.

```
Foo[x__?EvenQ] := x^2;
Foo[2, 4]
```

which is equal to `Sequence[2,4]^2` which in turns equal to `65536`.

What does it mean? Why is it `65536`? I really don't understand what kind of algorithm is applied here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switching away from infix notation might make things more clear:

```
Sequence[2, 4]^2 === Power[Sequence[2, 4], 2] === Power[2, 4, 2]
```

According to the documentation of [`Power`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html#268315285):
[image]

and so we have

```
Power[2, 4, 2] == 2^(4^2) == 65536
```